# Pass $(this) to a Binded Callback Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, bind

I am trying to understand the difference between these two callback methods and how they handle the `$(this)` context.

**Working Example**

```
$("#container").on("click",".button", function() {
    $(this).text("foo");
});
```

This process works just fine. However, if I want to do a different approach, I lose the context of the event.

**Non-Working Example**

```
bindAnEventToAnElement: function(theElement, theEvent, theFunctions) {
    $("body").on(theEvent, theElement, function() {
        theFunctions();
    });
}

bindAnEventToAnElement(".button", "click", function() { 
    $(this).text("foo"); 
});
```

The latter produces an undefined error. Is there a way I can handle callbacks like this while retaining the context of the event?

**Fiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/szrjt6ta/

Comment: You could just do `$("body").on(theEvent, theElement, theFunctions);` and the context will be correct. It's all about the context here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, jquery's `this` in that callback function refers to the `event.currentTarget` value. So, you should also pass the event object and do something like this:

```
 $("#container").on("click", ".button", function () {
     $(this).text("foo");
 });

 theApp = {
     bindAnEventToAnElement: function (theElement, theEvent, theFunctions) {
         $("body").on(theEvent, theElement, function (e) {
             theFunctions.apply(this /* or e.currentTarget */, arguments);
         });
     }
 }

 theApp.bindAnEventToAnElement(".button-two", "click", function () {
     $(this).text("foo");
 });
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/szrjt6ta/9/)**

If I try to explain the problem, jquery is binding the callback function to pass this as  `e.currentTarget`. But you are passing an another callback function inside that callback function whose scope will not be its parent callback function but will be the `window`. So, you need to again bind the `this` to the wrapped function, which you can do using [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) or [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

Comment: What is 'arguments' in this example?

Comment: @Yuschick every function has `this` and `arguments` variables. (_they are registered_). Here `arguments` is array of the parameters you passed to that function. You better check MDN for better explanation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Comment: thank you for the explanation and link. After a bit more of an real-case-scenario test, I think this is going to work nicely for me.  Thank you very much!

Comment: @Yuschick welcome, I improved my explanation. Hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 1):

You have to manually bind the context to the function in order to have `this` valorized inside your callback:

```
$("body").on(theEvent, theElement, function() {
    theFunctions.apply(this);
});
```

**example** http://jsfiddle.net/szrjt6ta/1/

Find more about `apply()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Comment: But can you explain what the issue is?  I'd like to understand. I also, ideally, would need to be able to pass this in my theFunctions argument.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the event, then use `$(e.target)`

https://jsfiddle.net/szrjt6ta/3/

Answer (score 0):

Use `.call(this)` The `call()` method calls a function with a given this value and arguments provided individually.

> Note: While the syntax of this function is almost identical to that of
>   apply(), the fundamental difference is that call() accepts an argument
>   list, while apply() accepts a single array of arguments.

```
 $("#container").on("click",".button", function() {
        $(this).text("foo");
    });

theApp = {
    bindAnEventToAnElement: function(theEvent, theElement, theFunctions) {
        $("body").on(theEvent, theElement, function() {
            theFunctions.call(this);
        });
    }
}

    theApp.bindAnEventToAnElement("click", ".button-two", function() { 
        $(this).text("fooe");
    });
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/szrjt6ta/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Change the event handler attachment from

```
$("body").on(theEvent, theElement, function() {theFunctions();});
```

to

```
 $("body " + theElement).on(theEvent, theFunctions);
```

Like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <a class="button">Button</a><br />
    <a class="button-two">Button Binded</a>
</div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$("#container").on("click",".button", function() {
    $(this).text("foo");
});

theApp = {
    bindAnEventToAnElement: function(theElement, theEvent, theFunctions) {
        $("body " + theElement).on(theEvent, theFunctions);
    }
}

theApp.bindAnEventToAnElement(".button-two", "click", function() {
    $(this).text("foo");
});
```

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/szrjt6ta/10/